# How to solve this recurrence relation related to the Group theoritic problem?

Tags: permutations, recurrence-relations

I was trying to count the number of elements of order 2 in the group $S_n$ and somehow translated the problem to the following recurrence relation.

$a_{n+1} = a_n + na_{n-1}$ with the initial conditions $a_0=0, a_1=1, a_2=2$ for $n \geq 3$

I don't know how to proceed after this stage. Kindly help.

Comment: Google for "linear recursion", or search on MSE - e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703996/linear-recursion-with-backtracking).

Comment: Also the number of elements of order $2$ in $S_n$ have been determined on MSE. For a start, read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311680/finding-the-number-of-elements-of-order-two-in-the-symmetric-group-s-4), and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340297/finding-the-number-of-elements-of-particular-order-in-the-symmetric-group?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: the solution is not so simple, see WolframAlpha

Comment: Sorry, add the condition $n \geq 3$

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, kindly provide me the link.

Comment: @joy Isn't it $n\ge 2$, otherwise, how do we get $a_3$ ?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(1)%3D1+,+a(2)%3D2+,+a(n%2B1)%3Da(n)%2Bna(n-1)

Comment: @Peter I am sorry but I don't call "solution" the output given by WA with this input...

Comment: @JeanMarie Apparantly, Wolfram Alpha does not find a solution, maybe there is no closed form. I posted the link because joy was interested in the output.